# Take photo automatically

Tags: android

In my app I want to take photo automatically every several seconds, so I tried to startActivity using the google IMAGE_CAPTURE intent and inject some key events. But I cant find the way to intent keyevent to activity not written by me. Anyone can suggest any other method?

Or else I have to write my own photo taking activity(it would cause a lot of time...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Anyone can suggest any other method?

Use the `Camera` class and take the picture yourself.

> Or else I have to write my own photo taking activity(it would cause a lot of time...)

Not for most developers.